# Windows in atexit() handler getting the current process exit code set by ::exit()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using `on_exit()` on linux, and the function gets the exit code as a parameter. I wanted to achieve the same on windows, and there is no API that provides this.

My idea was calling `GetExitCodeProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), &exitcode)`, but it gives me `STILL_ACTIVE (259)`.

In the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) it is stated, that the last thing happens during exit, that the real exit code replaces the `STILL_ACTIVE`.
Can I retrieve the real exit code somehow? I know the `::exit()` was called, because the function being run was registered by `atexit()`.

Comment: No equivalent on Windows, structurally unsound because a process can terminate for reasons other than exiting main().  No atexit() functions run, the exit code is set to the termination reason.  If it is essential then use a separate guard process.

Comment: guard process would be a 100% good idea, but in my case it's not feasible. I don't even care if the handler is not being run on _exit(), whenever the handler is being run the exitcode (so far known) would suffice. **IF** i'm already in the handler, i **know** that the process already started the exiting phase, and the exit code is already known (may change if other handlers set it differently, but that does not really matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest way to get the exit code would be another guard process.
if that's not an option you could hook the ExitProcess function and get the exit code from that.

Comment: Thank you. ExitProcess would be a bit too late I think.